# create a list of files from a directory with various parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

My folder has .jpg files as follows:

```
D:\\myfolder\\a.b2001001.c05.jpg
D:\\myfolder\\a.b2001002.c08.jpg
D:\\myfolder\\a.b2001003.c07.jpg
D:\\myfolder\\a.b2001004.c09.jpg
...
...
D:\\myfolder\\a.b2001080.c11.jpg
```

How can I select only files ranging from a.b2001003 to a.b2001050? (question 1)
How can I select only files containing c05, c08, and c09 ? (question 2)

```
import glob
files = glob.glob ("D:\\myfolder\\????.jpg")
```

Comment: Use regex direclty .. pipe your glob.glob into your regex .. see answer below ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using only glob.glob() will not produce what you want.

Using list comprehension:

```
import glob
import os

files = glob.glob("D:\\myfolder\\a.b*.c0[589].jpg")
files = [f for f in files if 2001003 <= int(os.path.basename(f)[3:10]) <= 2001050]
```

Answer (score 0):

`import glob`

`import re`

`s = ''.join(glob.glob('/path/to/direc/*'))`

files ranging from c05, c08, c09 :-

`re.findall("a\.b[0-9]{7}\.c[0][5|8|9]\.JPG", s)`

files ranging from a.b2001003 to a.b2001050

`re.findall("a.b20010[0-5][3-9]\.JPG", s)`

Hope this helps somehow ... :)